# Why restoring checkpoint is run on CPU not GPU?

Tags: tensorflow

I am training GAN with **tensorpack**, after training finished, here is the log file:

```
2019-04-19 10:14:19.311373: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2019-04-19 10:14:19.374343: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:895] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-04-19 10:14:19.374547: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1105] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1060 3GB major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.759
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 2.94GiB freeMemory: 2.17GiB
2019-04-19 10:14:19.374562: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1195] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060 3GB, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
[0419 10:14:20 @base.py:211] Initializing the session ...
[0419 10:14:20 @base.py:218] Graph Finalized.
[0419 10:14:20 @concurrency.py:37] Starting EnqueueThread QueueInput/input_queue ...
[0419 10:14:20 @base.py:250] Start Epoch 1 
...
[0419 10:25:45 @base.py:250] Start Epoch 5
100%|#######################################|10000/10000[02:51<00:00,58.38it/s]
[0419 10:28:36 @base.py:260] Epoch 5 (global_step 50000) finished, time:2 minutes 51 seconds.
```

and here is **nvidia-smi** info

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.130                Driver Version: 384.130                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 106...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 59%   67C    P2    74W / 120W |    965MiB /  3010MiB |     93%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1371      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           313MiB |
|    0      2293      G   compiz                                       192MiB |
|    0      2823      G   ...uest-channel-token=17545882067829269512   131MiB |
|    0      7632      G   ...-token=7C806614AA650E661A2E8895D83D4B4E    41MiB |
|    0      7824      G   /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/TeamViewer             13MiB |
|    0     28413      C   python3                                      269MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see the training is run on GPU and it just took a few minutes to finish an epoch.
But after finishing training, the checkpoint will be restored. But I found out that it was restored on CPU not GPU 
here is the log file and **nvidia-smi**

```
2019-04-19 10:28:55.169308: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2019-04-19 10:28:55.236758: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:895] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-04-19 10:28:55.236987: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1105] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1060 3GB major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.759
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 2.94GiB freeMemory: 2.20GiB
2019-04-19 10:28:55.237005: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1195] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060 3GB, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
  7%|##7                                    |700/10000[14:36<3:14:43, 0.80it/s][0419 10:28:55 @sessinit.py:117] Restoring checkpoint from train_log/TGAN_synthesizer:ISOT-1/model-50000 ...
 16%|#####9                                |1574/10000[31:59<2:51:25, 0.82it/s] 16%|######1                               |1606/10000[32:37<2:47:25, 0.84it/s]



+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.130                Driver Version: 384.130                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 106...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 41%   42C    P8     7W / 120W |    665MiB /  3010MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1371      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           313MiB |
|    0      2293      G   compiz                                       196MiB |
|    0      2823      G   ...uest-channel-token=17545882067829269512    97MiB |
|    0      7632      G   ...-token=7C806614AA650E661A2E8895D83D4B4E    41MiB |
|    0      7824      G   /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/TeamViewer             13MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Why restoring checkpoint is run on CPU not GPU? It took me so long to restore checkpoint on CPU. How do I configure to restore checkpoints on GPU?

Comment: Include your code snippet for detailed analysis.

Comment: Hmmmm very good question, but I dont know why